# Balancing/equalizing color of geotiffs before creating mosaic

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-merge

I have multiple geotiffs and I want to balance/equalize the color between them, so when I create the final mosaic there will not be any "too obvious" artefacts.

GDAL helps to create the mosaic (as shown in several posts) but how can I do the trick for the color?

Comment: You need histogram matching. Scikit skimage Python module has an explosure object which can help. See https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2021/02/08/histogram-matching-with-opencv-scikit-image-and-python/ and https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.exposure.html

Comment: Thanks for that, a quick search provides this one also https://github.com/mapbox/rio-hist

Comment: I've also a small Python CLI program here: https://github.com/OSGeoLabBp/tutorials/tree/master/english/img_processing